# Issue converting Matlab code to Python non-broadcastable output

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have the following code in Matlab

```
a= a + b(c,:);
```

where 'a' is a 4524x3 matrix, 'b' is 1131x3 and 'c' 4524x1.

In Python I have

```
a[:]+= b[c, :]
```

Where I'm getting 'a' as a 4524x4524x3 matrix. Why does Python create this extra dimension instead of sum the values?

Comment: What are the exact dimensions of `c`?  What happens when you do `c.shape` in the command prompt?  Do you get `(4524,)` or `(4524,1)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this instead:

```
a[:] += b[c.ravel(), :]
```

What's happening is that `c` is considered as a two-dimensional matrix rather than a single 1D array, which is why the unnecessary broadcasting is happening. You are basically trying to index the matrix with a 2D array when you need it to be 1D.